# protobuf: text_format module complains about "a byte like object is required"

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I recently started using protobuf. I got a problem as below:

I created a protobuf message, filled in some content, and wrote the text format to disk:

```
f = open('/home/centos/pb.conf','w')
f.write( text_format.MessageToString(c))
```

now I try to read the protobuf out from disk, back into the python object:

```
c2=cf.Configure()
input = open('/home/centos/pb.conf','rb')
b = input.read()
text_format.Merge(b, c2)
```

then, sadly, I got this error:

```
    471   return MergeLines(
--> 472       text.split('\n'),
    473       message,
    474       allow_unknown_extension,

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

however, it seems that the message in 'b' is bytes-format:

```
Out[49]: b'name: "david"\ncar_fe_config {\n  name: "style_slow"\n}\nfleet_fe_config {\n  name: "style_fast"\n}\n'
```

any clue what happened?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because [`Merge()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.text_format-pysrc#Merge) has an internal method, `MergeLines()`, which splits on a string representation of a newline (`"\n"`).  If you pass in a byte representation it would have to split on `.split(b"\n")` to avoid an error, but the splitter is hard-coded as a string.

Try reading your saved data as a string (e.g. use `open(<filename>, 'r')` instead of `'rb'`), that should work.